# Angular 2: Styling router-outlet to have width < 100%

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template

I'm building an Angular 2 app which would have a side nav bar for screens wider than 500, and a bottom nav bar for screens less wide than 500. For now I was trying to assign a 20% width to the side bar, 80% to app content.

The problem that I have is that the router-outlet content (i.e. the actual app) takes up the full width of the page instead of just 80%. It seems to be ignoring any styling I try to give it. Are we not supposed to style router-outlet directly? Or perhaps there is a better way that I'm overlooking?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav *ngIf="this.window.innerWidth > 500"></nav>
      <router-outlet style="width:80%;float:right;"></router-outlet>
      <nav *ngIf="this.window.innerWidth < 500"></nav>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  window = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.window.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.window.innerWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
    console.log(this.window.innerWidth);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Simple solution is to just put `<router-outlet>` in a styled `div`:

```
<div style="width:80%;float:right;">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: This technique doesn't work if you use 2 different layouts. The div region is drawn even if it doesn't belong to the 2nd layout.

Answer (score 20):

By using `:host` we can modify the style while loading the component.

```
:host(selector) { width:70% }
```

Following is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-selector',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent{
}

//test.component.css content
:host(test-selector) { width:70% } will reduce the width to 70%
```

Answer (score 8):

The key is [/deep/](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#-deep-) keyword:

```
:host /deep/ router-outlet + *:not(nav) {
   width:80%;
   float:right;
}
```

Since the component is dynamically loaded right after  tag, the selector '+' matches anything next to it.

And the :not() selector excludes  element in your template.

### Edited 2018/3/1:

Since [Angular 4.3.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#430-2017-07-14) made `/deep/` deprecated, its suggested alternative is `::ng-deep`. And there were a [long discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867) about this.

Comment: /deep/ is deprecated.

Comment: Use ::ng-deep instead of /deep/

Answer (score 3):

Use host:{'style':'width:70%'} within @Component({}) in the component file to set the width of child

Answer (score 0):

you could do the same with css grid. as width the accepted answer, it seems to only work in a surrounding div