# How to remove router-outlet tag in rendered html?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

For some reason **Angular 2** inserts these `placeholder tags` (for the lack of a better word) like `router-outlet`

In other words, for a basic **app.component.ts** like this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector   : 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent
{
}
```

this html output gets rendered in browser:

```html
<router-outlet>
  Component rendered html content...
</router-outlet>

OR

<app-root>
  Component rendered html content...
</app-root>
```

instead of just having the component content inserted directly in html, like this:

```html
<p>Component rendered html content...</p>
```

---

### Edit

---

The existence of the router-outlet tag is preventing my css rules from being applied to (or even match) the component inner html tags

Is there a way I can change this behavior and get rid of the `<app-route>` (& other similar) tags?

---

NB. I'm new to Angular 2

Comment: possible duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43538081/681830

Comment: Format in your own css style for "app-root" and "router-outlet" like the rest of your <p>. [link in StOvr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017615/angular-2-styling-router-outlet-to-have-width-100)

Comment: @Val same answer in same minute, with same opinion. can mark this as dup.

Comment: @FooBar I'll do that if I have permission to =)

Comment: @Val: not really, I'm asking to get rid of app-route, not how to apply styles. The underlying html/css templates used are way too complicated to start messing with them

Comment: @FooBar: see my comment to Val

Comment: @TheDude surely its much more difficult to change something that Angular does automatically, than to check the answer provided to re-style those tags.

Comment: @FooBar: I actually *did* read the answer and went to angular website. see my comment to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Into your styles.css file:

```
 :host /deep/ router-outlet{
//here you put your <p> css code for router-outlet
        display: block;
        border: 10px solid black;
    }
     :host /deep/ app-root{
//here you put your <p> css code for app-root
        display: block;
        border: 10px solid black;
    }
```

in case some rule you add you dont see it gets applied, add !important to the rule:

```
border: 10px solid black !important;
```

As an extra:

```
:host /deep/ router-outlet + *:not(nav) {
   width:80%;
   float:right;
}
```

the :not() selector excludes element in your template.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you say I need to add `:host /deep/` to every single rule that applies to html elements inside all my components. Changing the existing html & css files would be a bad decision in this case, that means many inspecting many CSS files / hundreds of css rules to modify

Comment: I know how to apply css, thank you. What I'm saying is that your proposed solution applies to simple cases. Unless I misread the angular documentation, I fail to see how adding a black border to `:host /deep/ router-outlet` via CSS would solve the gazillion issues with other CSS rules

Comment: ...You?
My solution applies to your question, stated problem was "this screws up styling" so thats what I tried to help you fix.
But to remove router-outlet or hide it, theres [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848062/angular-2-show-hide-router-outlet-and-redirect-to-html-page)

Comment: Yes, I did get your intention when using borders, thank you. I edited my question, may be the issue is more clear now?

Comment: can´t you simply copy those styles you want applied to "<p>" (as you stated wanted result as: <p>Component rendered html content...</p>) and also put them into the code I provided? That will mean to have 3 times same css, for <p>, <router-outlet> and <app-root>, i think this is the easiest way to do it, and check if it generates "gazillions of issues" in css. Can´t help you further, sorry, can´t find how to get rid of them easily.

Comment: I wish I could, I'm using metronic admin theme as the base for this webapp and there are way too many pages / styles rules to change :(

Comment: Okay this is thinking out of the box, a little routine in javascript that changes from <app-root> to <p>, [you will have to modify the code but...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843680/how-to-replace-dom-element-in-place-using-javascript) This is not what should be done, but, maybe easier in your code than touching css, depends entirely on you.